# Pull request build is not showing issues in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines, pull-request

I have a PR analysis done on a project in Azure pipeline and the analysis doesnt show up any issues in sonarUI for the code.
But when the PR is merged in to the branch and analysis is performed then the issues are generated for the same piece of code.

using SonarQube 8.5

Could someone explain the reason??

Answer (score 0):

What type of Azure DevOps are you using? The cloud offering, **Azure DevOps Services** (**VSTS**)? Or the on-premises offering, **Azure DevOps Server** (**TFS**)?

According to the introduction from the docs about [**Pull Request Analysis**](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/) in **SonarQube**, it seems that **Azure DevOps Services** is not supported for **Pull Request Analysis** in **SonarQube**.

If you are using **Azure DevOps Services**, you can try the method below to see if it can work:

- Install a [**Self-hosted agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) on the machine your **SonarQube** server is hosting. And use this agent to run your pipeline. **Before analyzing your Pull Requests, make sure the Pull Request branch is checked out.**

**[UPDATE]**

According to your comments,

> I have a PR analysis done on a project in Azure pipeline and the analysis doesnt show up any issues in sonarUI for the code. But when the PR is merged in to the branch and analysis is performed then the issues are generated for the same piece of code.

The PR build and the CI build have the same configuration, and the only difference is the trigger type. Due to the CI build can work as expected, the configuration you set in the Azure pipeline should be correct.

> I see this happenning intermittently...previously with 8.0 version this issue never happened..after the upgradation to 8.5..I can see this issue happening

You can try the build pipeline with version 8.0 to see if it still works as expected. And compare the output logs in the build pipeline between version 8.0 and 8.5.

If it works fine on version 8.0, it means the Azure pipeline can work normally, and the issue should occur on the version 8.5 itself. If so, I recommend that you can open a topic on the [**SonarSource Community**](https://community.sonarsource.com/) to get more help.

Comment: Hello, am using Azure DevOps Services (VSTS)..I have seen PR analysis is working fine for few pull reqs where  the analysis results are showing and for few the result is showing pass and anaylsis is not happening...I see this happenning intermittently...previously with 8.0 version this issue never happened..after the upgradation to 8.5..I can see this issue happening

Comment: Hi @PadmapriyaKp, thanks for your reply. according to your comments, I think the issue may occur on the version 8.5 itself. I have update my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: Is it recommended to run SonarQube analysis automatically on every CI build/Git commit?